# Need to convert date and time in R to this format '201712071520' for a Weather API call

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate, weather-api

How can I convert dates in R to a string without dashes or slashes or letters and times without colons.  For example I can get 2017-12-07 in R but I need 201712071520 to use in an Weather API call.  How can I do that?  For reference please see the example call below for startDateTime and endDateTime.  I would like to convert the dates that I have into 20171207 format and append it with a fixed time (1520) without the colon.  Thanks for helping!

I have been told this question has been asked before but the other examples are doing the opposite converting character strings into R dates and times.

Here is an example of the API I am calling:

https://api.weather.com/v3/wx/hod/conditions/historical/point?pointType=nearest&geocode=39.86,-104.67&startDateTime=201712071520&endDateTime=201712071520&units=e&format=json&apiKey=yourApiKey

Comment: Dirk, Please show me where the exact duplicate is because i cannot find it, thanks Michael

Comment: Dirk your example is how to convert a character into R.  I am looking to do the opposite and convert from R into a character string 201712071520

Comment: Have moved comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Moved from comments.

If `x` is of R's `"Date"` class then use the indicated `format` statement:

```
x <- as.Date("2017-12-07") # test input

format(x, "%Y%m%d1520") 
## [1] "201712071520"
```

See `?strptime` for more on percent codes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more generic solution. It would look like this:

```
    library(lubridate)
    input_date = "2017-1-7" #intentionally taking different date to make it more generic
    fixed_text = "1520"
    input_date = ymd(input_date)
    output_date = paste(year(input_date), sprintf(fmt = '%02d', month(input_date)), sprintf(fmt = '%02d', day(input_date)), fixed_text, sep = "")
    print(output_date)
```